# What advantages does Ceylon have over Java or Scala

Tags: java, scala, ceylon

Yesterday I saw the [announcement](http://ceylon-lang.org/blog/2011/12/20/ceylon-m1-newton/?utm_source=news&utm_medium=web&utm_content=newslink&utm_campaign=1_0_M1release) from the Ceylon team that the first milestone release had been made publicly available. And from what I can see, it looks intersting.

From looking at the information on Ceylon, its purpose seems largely in line with the purpose of Scala...

> Ceylon is deeply influenced by Java. You see, we're fans of Java, but
>   we know its limitations inside out. Ceylon keeps the best bits of Java
>   but improves things that in our experience are annoying, tedious,
>   frustrating, difficult to understand, or bugprone.

So, in a nutsheel, Ceylon and Scala seem to be saying (in my interpretation) *We Like Java, but there are annoyances, so we want to build on top of Java to make life better.*

But want I want to know is, why create Yet-Another-Java-Killer, as some have billed Ceylon, when Scala already exists? What sets Ceylon apart, or above Scala?

Note: Please no "I like X over Y", I am looking for an objective view of what Ceylon offers the development community.

Comment: You might be interested in this [discussion](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117561/whats-the-difference-between-scala-and-red-hats-ceylon-language).

Comment: I kind of think this should be on programmers; not really a good SO question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The team behind Ceylon claims Scala is to difficult/complex/complicated and tried to create something that is simpler.

The echo that comes back from the Scala community is that Scala isn't difficult, and that Ceylon misses a lot of the important power of Scala.

It's hard to even think about this without getting into a flame war.

Comment: Scala at first glance can be scary, and I guess Ceylon makes the transition less painful for Java developers. Interesting to see what the adoption is like over time

Comment: @Codemwnci I agree. But what looks scary in the beginning often turns out really nice and powerful ... time will tell

Comment: The main one for me is "first-class and higher-order functions". This is one of the main features missing in Java, and present in Scala. It's on Ceylon's to-do list, but I'm surprised they even released without baking in such a core feature.

Comment: One advantage over Scala seems to be the way `null`-s are treated. In Scala, if you want to avoid NPE-s, you can use `Option[T]`, but references are still `null`-able, and the conversion between `Option[T]` and plain references is not implicit (by default, but it's not recommended to make it implicit). Ceylon's way of doing this, with type unions (`T?` is shorthand for `T|Nothing`), is much much safer and much more convenient. It's almost impossible to cause NPE-s in Ceylon, and you never has to write stuff like `Some(foo)`.

Answer (score 4):

The M1 release misses important features, as listed in your link. As long as these are not delivered, Ceylon is basically just a Java with a nicer syntax. Once these features are available, there would be certainly a considerable advantage over Java, but not over Scala, which already has these features right now and more (most notably higher kinded types). Of course still syntax plays an important role, but that's mostly a matter of taste and excellent fuel for flame wars.

Comment: +1 and small correction: they have most likely no higher kinded type *variables*. Isn't it funny, people scream for lambdas and higher order functions and have yet to discover that one needs higher kinded type vars to write really abstract code.